# Vertical-align using CSS and DIV

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my comments centered vertically. However, it just doesn't work to work.
I've attached the code and a screenshot of the actual positions.

What is wrong?

```
.comment {
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

..the HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div class="profile_picture_container">
            <img class="profile_picture" src="URL" />
        </div>
        <div class="comment">
            <b>Patrick Reck</b> Come on, would you just work already!
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: ps: Use `<strong>` instead of `<b>`. The latter has been deprecated.

Comment: vertical-align: middle is really undependable... i never use it, b.c it never seems to work right or not at all

Comment: @lawnlanders - Vertical-align is totally dependable for modern browsers. Problems generally arise when one doesn't properly understand what box is being aligned within what other box. It's the layout and dimensions of those boxes which can be hard to perceive sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout) specification

> the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the height of the row, but it does not increase the height of the cell box.

The expected result you can get with fixed valued Height element.

So You can try this

```
.comment {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3A7zm/)

Answer (score 0):

float and display don't work together.

a table cell vertical-center itself on middle .

img , is inline-box and vertical centers among text or other inline-boxes.

You can simply make your html like this:

```
<td>
  <img />
  <span>text</span>
</td>
```

and your css like this:

```
    td,
    td img,
    td span {vertical-align:middle;}
    /* turn span into an inline boxe */
    td span {display:inline-block;
    /* you may need a max-width or set 
    white-space to "no-wrap" on td and back to "normal" on span  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of having a bet both ways by using divs in table cells. Why not ditch the table altogether and use divs? Here's an example: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/JmzEe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
.wrap {
    display: table;
    min-height: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: red;
}

.wrap div.comment {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="profile_picture_container">
        <img class="profile_picture" src="URL" />
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <b>Patrick Reck</b> Come on, would you just work already!
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```